# asp.net Chart databind does not accept Time datatype from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

When I set up a chart that databind to SQL Server, I select RPO_Drift that had datatype Time(hh:mm:ss) for Y axis and Actual_Time that had datatype DateTime (Date+HH:MM:SS). When I run the browser, there is a error said, `Series data points do not support values of type System.TimeSpan only values of these types can be used: Double, Decimal, Single, int, long, uint, ulong, String, DateTime, short, ushort.`

It does support DateTime but does not support Time. Is there way around like convert it or something to be able to display Time on Y axis chart?

Comment: Why not just use a string? You can format time output in any way you want, especially in your asp.net code.

Comment: To convert a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` all you need is a starting date. You can add `TimeSpan` objects to `DataTime` objects and the result is a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show durations in an ASP.NET Bar Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364652/show-durations-in-an-asp-net-bar-chart)